# Regroup data automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to group data in my Excel in a automatic way (by using a macro) 
For example, in my column A, I have fields tuck as this:

- in A1 I have " 1.0.1",
- in A2 " 1.0.3",
- in A3 " 1.0.5",
- in A4 " 1.1.1",
- in A5 " 1.1.2".

I would like to group these data so as to have two groups: 1.0 (packaging A1, A2 and A3) and 1.1 (packaging A4 and A5).

The problem is that the data which can vary (addition of one given 1.0.7 for example which it will be necessary to group(include) in 1.0)

So, it would be necessary to read all the fields of the column A and to make a regroupage by comparing the first 3 characters of every fields, and so to group what is identical.

It is possible to make that in Visual Basic ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Every time you add new data, simply ungroup and sort the data. Once the data is sorted, regroup the data. You might want to record a macro to see how grouping/ungrouping works?

Comment: What have you tried? The answer is as @SiddharthRout says, yes, it is possible. However this website is NOT A code writing service - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
sub regrouper()
  Worksheets.Add.Name="group1"
  Worksheets.Add.Name="group2"
  Dim g1Row As Integer
  Dim g2Row As Integer
  Dim splitter(0 to 4) As String

  g1Row = g2Row = 2

  For Each cell in Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Range("A65536").End(xlup).Row)
    splitter = Split(cell.text, ".")
    If splitter(1) = 0 then
      Worksheets("group1").Range("A" & g1Row).Value = cell.Value
      g1Row = g1Row + 1
    ElseIf splitter(1) = 1 then
      Worksheets("group2").Range("A" & g2Row).Value = cell.Value
      g2Row = g2Row + 1
    Else
      MsgBox("data not in group 1 or 2")
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

not tested but should get you a little closer